# "Safari cannot find the server" when accessing GitHub on MacBook using personal hotspot from iPhone

Tags: networking, macos, iphone

I encountered a very strange problem that I couldn't find anybody ever reported anywhere using Google.

On my MacBook using my iPhone SE's personal hotspot, it is almost not possible to access GitHub. It may work once at the beginning (i.e. the first connection), then "Safari cannot find the server", and after waiting for 15-20 minutes, it may work again.

Some important observations:

- The issue does not happen for any other websites than GitHub.
- On the iPhone, it works. Thus the phone's 4G connection is not an issue.
- Using another iPhone (6S) with another 4G network (different carrier) as personal hotspot, it works.

I've desperately searched for a solution on Google but it seems nobody ever had the same issue.

Could you please help? Thank you very much in advance!

**Update:** Google Chrome doesn't work either, so the issue is not specific to Safari.

Comment: I’d take a look at the output of `curl -v https://github.com` on both hosts. See if it’s safari or the network intercepting traffic.

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks for your comment. I obtained: `Could not resolve host: github.com`. However, I can access GitHub on Safari...

Comment: @jsbillings Currently I have no issue accessing GitHub on Safari, but I think it is coming soon, I'll run again `curl` to see if there's a difference.

Comment: @jsbillings Now I can no longer access GitHub on Safari and, unsurprisingly, `curl` gave `Could not resolve host: github.com`...

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't work either.

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. Can you turn on DNS over TLS on Firefox?

Comment: @jsbillings It works, indeed!! I tried using Cloudflare's DNS in macOS's network settings and now it works everywhere (browser + terminal). Thanks a lot! Please post as an answer so that I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an DNS issue (thanks to @jsbillings for pointing out). Using Cloudflare's DNS is a workaround.